# Fork() denied on iOS 12

Tags: ios, ios12

My app is trying to perform Jailbreak detection by calling Fork() but iOS denies the call and following error message is received "**deny(1) process-fork**". I am unable to understand why this call would fail on Jailbroken device.

Comment: Jailbreak compromises iOS kernel App signature checking not the iOS application sandbox. Since particular iOS version (not sure which one exactly) Apple made the sandbox enforced  ruleset more restrictive and disallows forking. In previous iOS versions it was possible to technically call fork in the sandbox but as the **final result** it would fail on non-jailbroken devices. Hence this particular way of jb detection is obsolete. If you really need to fork on the jailbroken device you can put your app in `/Applications/` instead not to be confined by the app sandbox.

Comment: @Kamil.S Got it. Is it the same reason as to why my app is unable to write in root directory even though the application runs on a jailbroken device?

Comment: I don't know if sandbox would block that, but even if not the root directory can be only written by root privileged user. You could try chowning to `root:0` your whole app directory through ssh, but obviously you'd be compromising security. Alternatively maybe a shell `su` through your app would work. Nowadays almost no system processes in iOS run with root privileges, interestingly that used to be the case for iOS 1.0.